# get separated values of ABPeoplePickerView

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3

how can i get the address values (city,street,zip) as separated values of a person which i selected in my ABPeoplePickerView?

```
   let person = PeoplePicker.selectedRecords as! [ABPerson]

    print(person[0].value(forProperty: "First"))
    print(person[0].value(forProperty: "Last"))
    print(person[0].value(forProperty: "Address"))
```

This is my print result:

```
Max
Mustermann
{
        *  home  {
    City = xxx;
    Street = "xxx";
    ZIP = xxx;
}  D
}
```

Code now:

```
let addressBook = ABAddressBook.shared()
        let people = addressBook?.people()
        for person in people! as! [ABPerson] {
            for property in ABPerson.properties() {
                if let multiValue = person.value(forProperty: (property as! NSString) as String!) as? ABMultiValue {
                    for identifier in multiValue {
                        let value: AnyObject = multiValue.valueForIdentifier(identifier as String)
                        print("\(identifier) : \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Error:

```
Type 'ABMultiValue' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
on line: for identifier in multiValue {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
let address = person[0].value(forProperty: kABAddressProperty) as! ABMultiValue
let zip = address.value(at: 0) as! NSMutableDictionary
print(y.value(forKey: kABAddressZIPKey))
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this example and modified for single contact.

```
let addressBook = ABAddressBook.sharedAddressBook()
let people = addressBook.people()
for person in people {
    for property in ABPerson.properties() {
        if let multiValue = person.valueForProperty(property as NSString) as? ABMultiValue {
            for identifier in multiValue {
                let value: AnyObject = multiValue.valueForIdentifier(identifier as String)
                println("\(identifier) : \(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: at first: i need a swift solution :/ and second thing: the code above works good. but i need a variable for each value (City, Street, ZIP)

Comment: i updated my first post with your code, which i have changed to be swift 4 conform. but i get an error

Answer (score 0):

Get Value is an array of labeled values with postal address values. A postal address has a “street” property, a “city” property, a “state” property, a “postalCode” property, a “country” property.

```
let array = person[0].value(forProperty: "Address") as! NSarray
```

get the value using label value you can get name seperated like city,state and postalcode.

Comment: thanks, but i get this error: `Could not cast value of type 'ABMultiValueCoreDataWrapper' (0x7fffd4972240) to 'NSArray' (0x7fffd5275c58).`

Answer (score 0):

```
let person = PeoplePicker.selectedRecords as! [ABPerson]

if let multiValue = person.valueForProperty(property as NSString) as? ABMultiValue {          
    println(multiValue.valueAtIndex(i))              
}
```

Comment: this gives me the result `{
    City = Neuss;
    Street = "Liegnitzer Str. 32";
    ZIP = 41469;
}` but not separated :(